# VSCode Autocomplete matching suggested case

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Autocomplete in Visual Studio doesn't match the suggested variable case.
Example: I've got a variable "$arrayTest". When I start writing the variable name, visual studio rightly suggests the complete variable, but it completes it without checking the case of what I wrote to that point. So in this situation, if I write "$arrayt" and autocomplete, VS will maintain "$arraytest" instead of "$arrayTest", which is a real pain. Is there any way to adjust this setting?

Sorry for my poor use of English, I sometimes have difficulty explaining myself.

Comment: Maybe you should report this issue to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out what actually was going wrong with autocompletion. Tried to reproduce the error unchecking some options, disabling extensions and features.

Anyway, you can try to:

1. Re-enable `@builtin php` Language Basics/Features
2. Run VS Code without extensions `code --disable-extensions` to make sure that no extension can effect autocompletion.
3. Temporarily comment out your user/workspace settings to make sure there is no tick affects.

You can also check out the autocompletion is working properly in other languages besides php.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I found out it was an Autocomplete extension I installed (All autocomplete).

Comment: @Nickelza Nice, man, glad to hear you figured it out. Some extensions may cause troubles that are a pain in the neck. If you check this as the best answer it would be great!